# Dymo printer C# interface barcode not working

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, barcode-printing, dymo

Looks like dymo print barcode has issue with .net framework 4.5.
If i use .net framework 3.5 barcode works fine.

Right now i have create a console app in .net framework 3.5 which is for printing dymo label

Main app is in .net 4.5 which call dymo print console app(.net 3.5).

Any other approach to solve this?

Comment: What do “not working” and “has issue” mean?

Comment: barcode print using .net 4.5 app is not recognizing by barcode scanner.